# Fixed route Home after google login with Socialite

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

I have setup a google login with socialite 3.2.0 on laravel 5.6.The authenticating does work great.I want a custom redirect, i tried my best with trying methods but it redirects to Home after registration.

```
//login controller
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';
    protected $redirectToEdit = '/edit';

    public function redirectToProvider($provider)
    {
        return Socialite::driver($provider)->redirect();
    }


    public function handleProviderCallback($provider )
    {
        $user = Socialite::driver($provider)->stateless()->user();
        $authUser = $this->findOrCreateUser($user, $provider);
        Auth::login($authUser,true);        
        return redirect($this->redirectToEdit);


    }

    public function findOrCreateUser($user, $provider)
    {
        $authUser = User::where('provider_id', $user->id)->first();
        if($authUser) {
            return $authUser;
        }
        $user =  User::create([
            'name'      =>  $user->name,
            'email'     =>  $user->email,
            'provider'  =>  strtoupper($provider),
            'provider_id'   =>  $user->id
        ]);


        return $user;
    }

routes
Route::get('auth/{provider}', 'Auth\LoginController@redirectToProvider');
Route::get('auth/{provider}/callback', 'Auth\LoginController@handleProviderCallback');
```

I want to direct the users using google as login to direct them to /edit after registration.How do i approach ?

Comment: This is how I have mine setup and it works fine. Your redirect function in the `handleProviderCallback` method should work as described. Is this line of code never being executed?

Comment: @MattWohler Thanks i changed the controller, now it is working, weird :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the controller worked.I had setup the user redirect function in LoginController and it redirected to /home instead of accessing the function.Changed to HomeController and setup the routes and it worked.

This is the approach i am currently having

```
return redirect()->route('edit'); // handleProviderCallback function in Login Controller

//routes
Route::get('test', 'HomeController@showForm')->name('edit');
```

You can either call the function directly as of [Laravel Redirects Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/redirects#redirecting-controller-actions)

```
return redirect()->action('HomeController@showForm');
```